# List Merge Commits in Specific Branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Is it possible to view a list of merge commits for a branch in git?

I'm looking to see only the merges that happened in a particular branch (without the other commits that were included in the merge).  Going based off of the commit message will not work in my situation.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man git-log`:

> --merges
>              Print only merge commits. This is exactly the same as --min-parents=2.

Try this:

```
git log --merges
```