# Find all merge events between two branches

Tags: git, merge, merge-base

I'm trying to determine the frequency with which master is merged into a specific release branch. So, I want to know the history of all merge-bases. Is there a way to list all of the merges that have happened between two branches?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762903/7976758 `git log --merges` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+merges

Comment: That's close, but doing `git log --merges` on branch `A` doesn't show me which merge commits are a result of merging in branch `B`. I want to see something like "all merge commits in A from B".

Comment: It's hardly possible — Git doesn't really remember to what branch a commit belonged in the past. Branches are just *current* pointers to commits. You can try to improve the list filtering it by commit message; it's only a guess, not a solution. Try `git log --merges --grep="Merge branch 'B'"`

Comment: I agree. A branch is merely a temporary name for one commit. You don't merge branches; you merge _commits_. The concept presupposed by the question is meaningless.

Comment: @phd Unfortunately `--grep` won't work as the merge commit messages don't include information about the merge operation (the commit message will be inherited automatically if there is no conflict).

Comment: The point is that it is your job to mark the merge commit in a searchable way if your plan is to do this kind of search later. You can use commit messages, tags, whatever. But only a human knows what you are looking for here; Git doesn't.

Comment: @matt I understand what you mean - but, please try to be a little flexible with language. It's normal to say "merge one branch into the other", even if one means "merge the commits of one branch after a common ancestor into the history of the other branch, starting from that common ancestor". Let's say it this way, I want a list of those commits in one branch, call it A, which also exist in another branch, call it B, such that each of those commits has more than one parent.

Comment: @matt git knows which commit hashes are common between two branches and which commits have more than one parent.

Comment: I know what is normal to _say_. But what we say about Git is often very misleading (such as the mistaken notion that a commit is "on" a branch).  I'm telling you what Git actually _is_.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you provide a solution to the following: I want a list of those commits in one branch, call it A, which also exist in another branch, call it B, such that each of those commits has more than one parent.

Comment: Or, roughly equivalently, can you provide a way to list a history of all merge-bases? I.e., if `git merge-base B` while on branch `A` returns abcdef1234 then I also want the result of `git merge-base abcdef1234~1`, and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell git log to output the commit hashes of the parent commits for each displayed commit :

```
git log --format="%p" --first-parent --merges release

# to get only second parents, just use awk or cut :
git log --format="%p" --first-parent --merges release | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

You can now check one by one whether each commit is part of branch `master`, perhaps using :

```
git rev-list --first-parent master | grep $sha
```

("the first parents of a branch" is the closest thing you will get to a history of that branch)

---

using a one liner :

```
git rev-list --format="%P" --first-parent --merges release | awk '{ print $2 }' |\
    grep -F -f <(git rev-list --first-parent master)
```

or adapting your usage of "uniq" in your comments:

```
(git rev-list --format="%P" --first-parent --merges release | awk '{ print $2 }';\
  git rev-list --first-parent master) | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: What do you think of the below?

`git checkout <release-branch> && echo "$(git --no-pager rev-list --merges HEAD)" "$(git --no-pager rev-list --merges master)" | uniq`

Comment: the merges you are looking for are part of `release` history, but not part of `master` history, `git rev-list --merges master` will not list commits you are interested in.

Comment: I actually want to only print those that are duplicated, and `uniq` won't work unless I sort, first, so `git checkout <release-branch> && echo "$(git --no-pager rev-list --merges HEAD)" "$(git --no-pager rev-list --merges master)" | sort | uniq -d` is better.

Comment: updated my answer : realized you would only look for merges in `release` *in the first parent history*

Comment: "the merges you are looking for are part of release history, but not part of master history". The commits I'm looking for _need_ to be a part of <release> history. I want to list commits that "came from" the master branch (`git merge master` when on <release>)

Comment: you may do your `uniq` trick by combining the output of my first command, and `git log --first-parent --format="%h" master` (when you specify `--format`, `git rev-list` and `git log` are basically synonyms)

Comment: your first one-liner yields empty results. Your second one-liner (`uniq`) looks like it could be right.

Comment: I fixed the options to `grep` : I had forgotten the `-f` (read patterns from a file). The `-F` (interpret all patterns as fixed strings) is only here to speed up things.

Comment: Ah, okay. We're getting closer, but now we have a consistency problem. I think your one-liner is not catching all of the possible common commits in the <release> branch and master. 

Your one-liner: `git rev-list --format="%P" --first-parent --merges HEAD | awk '{ print $2 }' |\
    grep -F -f <(git rev-list --first-parent master) | wc -l` returns 384 

`echo "$(git --no-pager rev-list --merges HEAD)" "$(git --no-pager rev-list --merges master)" | sort | uniq -d | wc -l` returns 83243 (closer to what I expect since `master` has ~350,000 commits and <release> merges a few times per day.

Comment: that kind of numbers ? :D To debug : replace raw `git rev-list` output with something like `--graph --format="%h %s - %p"` (`%h %s` will give short hash + one line message for each commit), and check if the list of commits you see in each case (`git rev-list --first-parent --merges release` and `git rev-list --first-parent master`) matches what you expect -- you can compare it with what you see in some other viewer of your repository.